# Entering mixed fractions into java

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am trying to enter 1 5/8 into my code but keep getting the following error:

run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 5/8"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
at ClientCode.main(ClientCode.java:42)

Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 17 seconds)
```

this is my code:

```
[code] public double findFrac(int whole, String frac) {
  if (frac == null || frac.equals(""))
    return whole;
String[] parts = frac.split("/");
return whole + Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) / (double)Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
```

Comment: `Double.parseDouble` doesn't understand fractions at all.  It would understand `1.625`, but not `1 5/8`.

Comment: Ok. That explains my error. Is there nothing I can use that would recognize them? I have to be able to enter the fractions into the JOptionPane window and receive a decimal in return once I print the output.

Comment: You have to write code to parse the fraction

Answer (score 1):

Java number parsing routines do not recognize mixed numbers like "1 5/8", or even fractions like "5/8". You will need to implement the logic for evaluating those strings yourself. One way is to separate your mixed number (by splitting the string on the space character), evaluate each piece separately, and add the results. When you evaluate the "5/8" part, you will need to split on the"/", evaluate the leading and trailing parts, and do float or double division.

For instance:

```
String data = "1 5/8";
String[] parts = data.split(" ");
float value = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
if (parts.length > 1) {
    // has fractional part
    parts = parts[1].split("/");
    float numerator = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    float denominator = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    value += numerator / denominator;
}
// value contains 1.625
```

Here's the same thing as a utility method:

```
public static float evaluateMixedFraction(String data)
    throws NumberFormatException
{
    String[] parts = data.split(" ");
    float value = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        // has fractional part
        parts = parts[1].split("/");
        float numerator = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        float denominator = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        value += numerator / denominator;
    }
    return value;
}
```

For a real application, you would probably want some additional error checking.

Comment: But what if I cannot place the actual data (1 5/8) in my code? I have to be able to enter this via the pop up window and the numbers/mixed fraction must change.

Comment: @AP - Hard-coding the data was just for purposes of illustration. In a real application, the assignment `String data = "1 5/8";` should simply be replaced by code that obtains the string via a pop-up window. (E.g., `String data = getUserInput();`.)

Comment: I see. Thank you. My next question would be if I did this I would label it as a method just as any other?

Comment: @AP - Absolutely. It would look something like `public String getUserInput() { /* code goes here */ }`. (Of course the name is entirely up to you, and it does not need to be `public` if it's in the same class.) Alternatively (and perhaps better), you would write my sample code as a method that takes a `String` argument and returns the evaluation: `public float evaluateMixedFraction(String data) { /* my code except for first line */ return value; }`. You'll probably want to put in some error checking; my code simply assumes that the user input is correctly formatted.

Comment: Oh ok. I would assume then leaving it as public String getUserInput() would be the less neat/clean way of doing things. Would the return on this also be UserInput? Yours definitely looks better. I hope with time and patience I can throw code together in a matter of seconds rather than hours.

Comment: Because for your code my tester would look like this:
    [code]input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Fraction");
         MixedFraction = Integer.parseInt(input);

Comment: @AP - I had in mind something more like this: `input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Fraction"); float value = evaluateMixedFraction(input);`

Comment: I've tried this and for whatever reason isn't working. Either way the method you are using is great and I'm afraid my study group will be confused by my results. Although, I am not sure if there is an easier more beginner like way of obtaining the same result.

Comment: @AP - In what way is it not working? It doesn't compile? Throws an exception? Produces the wrong result? Something else?

Comment: I have deleted everything and this is what I have now:
      [code]  public static void main(String[] args)
        String name;
        int shares;
        int portion1;
        int portion2;
        double computeDollars;
        evaluateMixedFraction;
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Company Name");
        name = input
        computeDollars = Double.parseDouble(input);
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Fraction"); 
        evaluateMixedFraction= evaluateMixedFraction(input);

Comment: @AP - So what's the problem now?

Comment: I deleted everything and tried to start over. I failed. I have to use integer division and mod. I just don't know how. Everything I use throws out an exception and it's wrong.

Comment: @AP - It's impossible to understand what's happening from these comments. Please post a new question showing **all relevant parts** of your current code and exactly what exception is being thrown, and from what line. Also, why are you using integer division and mod when you want a floating point result?

Comment: He asked that for this study we use integer division and mod to obtain the result. I understand that for someone with more experience perhaps this makes no sense but for whatever reason this is the route he wants us to take.

Comment: @AP - Integer division and mod make sense if you want to _generate_ or _normalize_ a mixed fraction, but not if you want to evaluate one as a numerical quantity. I guess it's not clear to me what you need to accomplish.

Comment: I understand. The class must include the price of a share of something in dollars and in eighths. Eighths ex: 1 1/8 and the user needs to be able to enter this into JOptionPane prompts as the numbers will continue to change. A method has to be made that will return the values entered as a decimal.

Comment: @AP - Like I said, start a new question (or questions). It sounds like you have several issues that you are dealing with at the same time, but please limit each question to one specific issue. For each question, post all the relevant code, a precise description of what you're trying to accomplish, what the problem is (including compiler error messages or stack traces from exceptions, as appropriate), and what else you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

The `Double.parseDouble` method doesn't understand fractions at all.  It doesn't know what to do with `1 5/8`; it needs something like `1.625`.

To parse fractions, you must either parse it yourself, or possibly some library somewhere might perform this task.

The [`Double.valueOf` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29), which also parses `Strings` (it just creates a `Double` instead of a `double`) goes to lengths to specify what is allowed and won't throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do fractions in java, or most other languages for that matter. Try [this class](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf98/labs/lab2/Fraction.java) instead.

Comment: That class does not parse mixed numbers (or does any parsing at all, as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you just have to **deal with strings**. If the input is correct, you have at least a part and at most three parts. These parts are only separated by space and slash, so you can separate them with a regular expression. e.g.:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(parseFraction("1 4/2"));
        System.out.println(parseFraction("6/2"));
        System.out.println(parseFraction("3"));
    }

    public static double parseFraction(String input) {
        String[] array = input.split("[ /]");
        switch (array.length) {
        case 1: // e.g. "1"
            return Double.parseDouble(array[0]);
        case 2: // e.g. "1/2"
            return Double.parseDouble(array[0]) / Double.parseDouble(array[1]);
        case 3: // e.g. "1 2/3"
            return Double.parseDouble(array[0]) + 
                    Double.parseDouble(array[1]) / Double.parseDouble(array[2]);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong input!");
        }
    }
}
```

The inputs are equivalent, so that output is the same for all cases:

```
3.0
3.0
3.0
```

Comment: Were supposed to go over this with a group and I'm afraid the "case" would confuse me...as I am already confused. I just need to have the user type in the input regardless of whether its a mixed fraction or not.

Comment: I feel stupid. I typed everything as you have it and nothing works. I only need the example with the mixed fraction.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) to parse the input.

the following is an example of how to parse the fraction:

```
static final String numberPatern="[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?";
static final Pattern pWhole = Pattern.compile("^("+numberPatern+")([\\s\\+-]|$)");
static final Pattern pFrac = Pattern.compile("("+numberPatern+")/("+numberPatern+")$");

static double fracToDouble(String in) {

    Matcher mWhole = pWhole.matcher(in);
    Matcher mFrac = pFrac.matcher(in);
    double d = 0;
    if (mWhole.find()) {
        String whole = mWhole.group(1);
        d += Double.valueOf(whole);
    }
    if (mFrac.find()) {
        String num = mFrac.group(1);
        String den = mFrac.group(3);
        d += Double.valueOf(num) / Double.valueOf(den);
    }
    return d;
}
```

it will correctly return 1.625 for one and five eights if any of the components is specified as a valid java floating point value:

- "1 5/8"
- "1+5/8"
- "1e0 -500e-2/-0.00080e4"